# UISegmentControl not functioning?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've hooked up a UISegmentControl in my navigation bar. It appears just fine, but when I tap the different segments, it doesn't execute cases 1 & 2 - it simply stays on case 0 (and thus, keeps logging "Requests!"). Any idea why this might be? See code below:

```
- (IBAction)segmentControl:(id)sender {

        switch (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
        {


            case 0:

                [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
                [self.neighboursView setHidden:YES];
                  [self.friendsView setHidden:YES];

                NSLog(@"Requests!");

                break;



            case 1: 

                [self.tableView setHidden:YES];
                [self.friendsView setHidden:NO];
                [self.neighboursView setHidden:YES];

                [self acceptedFriends];
                     NSLog(@"Friends!");

                break;



            case 2:

                [self.tableView setHidden:YES];
                [self.neighboursView setHidden:NO];
                [self.friendsView setHidden:YES];

                [self neighbourInfo];
                     NSLog(@"Neighbours!");
                break;


        }


    }
```

Comment: how did you make the connection to trigger the action? TouchUpInside or ValueChanged?

Comment: @BJHStudios ValueChanged

Comment: How have you added segment control in navigation bar?  As title view?

Comment: Possibly undefined behaviour because of bit misconnection exists bet navCont and uisegment, try adding programatically.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR I simply dragged a UISegmentControl into the navigation bar on storyboard, and connected/defined it in the .h file as a property. Is this not the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
    -(IBAction)segmentControl:(id)sender {

      UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
      NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

      switch (selectedSegment)
            {
             case 0:
            .

            .

            .
            }
     }
```

Comment: Then i think op has written lesser code to config the same and he is asking something diff not the syntax code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Simply drag and drop segment control on  Storyboard navigation bar.

Create Value Change action

[image]

```
- (IBAction)segmentValueClick:(id)sender {

    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

    switch (selectedSegment)
    {
        case 0:



            NSLog(@"Requests!");
            _lblText.text=@"Requests";
            break;



        case 1:


            NSLog(@"Friends!");
            _lblText.text=@"Friends";
            break;



        case 2:

           _lblText.text=@"Neighbours";
            NSLog(@"Neighbours!");
            break;

        default:

               NSLog(@"Default case!");
            break;


    }

}
```

[image]